# Optimal data structure for a large number of (float) values

Tags: java, android, arrays, memory-management

I'm developing a visualization app for Android (including older devices running Android 2.2).

The input model of my app contains an area, which typically consists of tens of thousands of vertices. Typical models have 50000-100000 vertices (each with an **x,y,z** `float` coord), i.e. they use up 600K-1200 kilobytes of total memory. The app requires all vertices are available in memory at any time. This is all I can share about this app (I'm not allowed to share high-level use cases), so I'm wondering if my below conclusions are correct and whether there is a better solution.

For example, assume there are `count`=50000 vertices. I see two solutions:

1.) My earlier solution was using an own `VertexObj` (better readability due to encapsulation, better locality when accessing individual coordinates):

```
public static class VertexObj { 
      public float x, y, z;
}

VertexObj mVertices = new VertexObj[count]; // 50,000 objects
```

2.) My other idea is using a large `float[]` instead:

```
float[] mVertices = new VertexObj[count * 3]; // 150,000 float values
```

The problem with the first solution is the big memory overhead -- we are on a mobile device where the app's heap might be limited to 16-24MB (and my app needs memory for other things too). According to the official [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation) pages, object allocation should be avoided when it is not truly necessary. In this case, the memory overhead can be huge even for 50,000 vertices:

First of all, the "useful" memory is 50000*3*4 = 600K (this is used up by `float` values). Then we have +200K overhead due to the `VertexObj` elements, and probably another +400K due to Java object headers (they're probably at least 8 bytes per object on Android, too). This is 600K "wasted" memory for 50,000 vertices, which is 100% overhead (!). In case of 100,000 vertices, the overhead is 1.2MB.

The second solution is much better, as it requires only the useful 600K for `float` values.

Apparently, the conclusion is that I should go with `float[]`, but I would like to know the risks in this case. Note that my doubts might be related with lower-level (not strictly Android-specific) aspects of memory management as well.

As far as I know, when I write `new float[300000]`, the app requests the VM to reserve a contiguous block of 300000*4 = 1200K bytes. (It happened to me in Android that I requested a 1MB `byte[]`, and I got an `OutOfMemoryException`, even though the Dalvik heap had much more than 1MB free. I suppose this was because it could not reserve a **contiguous** block of 1MB.)

Since the GC of Android's VM is not a compacting GC, I'm afraid that if the memory is "fragmented", such a huge`float[]` allocation may result in an OOM. If I'm right here, then this risk should be handled. E.g. what about allocating more `float[]` objects (and each would store a portion such as 200KB)? Such linked-list memory management mechanisms are used by operating systems and VMs, so it sounds unusual to me that I would need to use it here (on application level). What am I missing?

If nothing, then I guess that the best solution is using a linked list of `float[]` objects (to avoid OOM but keep overhead small)?

Comment: Implement a swap? :p Seriously, you can do everything as long as you keep the dirt `private`. Maybe behind a `float get(int index)`.

Comment: The app requires (for reasons not mentioned in my post) that I don't touch the disk after the first loading. In other words, I need all vertices in memory.

Comment: 3 parallel arrays would make it possibly easier to allocate that much memory since it can come in 3 chunks, 1/3 as large. But your solution is likely cache-friendlier since accesses will be more localized.

Comment: I was thinking to that too, but it often happens that x,y,z of the same vertex is needed at the same time. The cache-friendliness (locality) you mention applies in such a case, right? If so, then a list of arrays (each with an element number of a multiple of 3) might be better than parallel arrays. Of course, benchmark might prove that the overhead of the parallel case is negligible in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out of memory you are facing while allocating the `float` array is quite strange.

If the biggest countinous memory block available in the heap is smaller then the memory required by the float array, the heap increases his size in order to accomodate the required memory.

Of course, this would fail if the heap has already reach the maximum available to your application. This would mean, that your application has exausted the heap, and then release a significant number of objects that resulted in memory fragmentation, and no more heap to allocate. However, if this is the case, and assuming that the fragmented memory is enough to hold the float array (otherwise your application wouldn't run anyawy), it's just a matter of allocating order.

If you allocate the memory required for the float array during application startup, you have plenty of countinous memory for it. Then, you just let your application do the remaining stuff, as the countigous memory is already allocated.

You can easly check the memory blocks being allocated (and the free ones) using `DDMS` in `Eclipse`, selecting yout app, and pressing `Update Heap` button.

Just for the sake of of avoiding misleading you, I've tested it before post, allocationg several contigous memory bloocks of `float[300000]`.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into a problem where I wanted to embed data for a test case. You'll have quite a fun time embedding huge arrays because Eclipse kept complaining when the function exceeded something like 65,535 bytes of data due to me declaring an array like that. However, this is actually a quite common approach.

The rest goes into optimization. The big question is this: would be worth the trouble doing all of that optimizing? If you aren't hard-up on RAM, you should be fine using 1.2 megs. There's also a chance that Java will whine if you have an array that large, but you can do things like use a fancier data structure like a LinkedList or chop up the array into smaller ones. For statically set data, I feel an array might be a good choice if you are reading it like crazy.

I know you can make .xml files for integers, so storing as an integer with a tactic like multiplying the value, reading it in, and then dividing it by a value would be another option. You can also put in things like text files into your assets folder. Just do it once in the application and you can read/write however you like.

As for double vs float, I feel that in your case, a math or science case, that doubles would be safer if you can pull it off. If you do any math, you'll have less chance of error with double, especially with an operation like multiplication. floats are usually faster. I'm not sure if Java does SIMD packing, but if it does, more floats can be packed into an SIMD register than doubles

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, your claim is only true when an array is initialized with **literals** from code. In my original post, the content of the huge array are read from external sources (no array is "embedded" to the source code). More precisely, no method body is allowed to be greater than 65K in Java (this has nothing to do with arrays directly).

Comment: That's what I meant by embedded